# Eclipse hangs when I use Content Assist

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers.

Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0)
Build id: 20200910-1200

I installed the JBoss tools plugin from the Eclipse Marketplace which is used for Hibernate. Then, after like a day, out of the blue the content assist stopped working. I wouldn't say JBoss is the culprit but I've read that installing plugins from the Eclipse marketplace seems to cause such errors. So whenever I tried to press Ctrl + Space for suggests, Eclipse would just hang and I had to force close it. Reinstalling it wouldn't be a solution for me as it's work through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such errors occur when you usually add a new plugin from Eclipse Marketplace, so do try uninstalling the plugin and see if the error goes off. Also...

For my case, I had to go to Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced.
I am not sure if this is the case for everyone, but I had these Default Proposal Kinds that didn't have any icon and were basically blank. Here in the image, "Basic proposals" and "WebSocket Proposals" were ticked and the icons were blank. I unchecked them and them and now the Content Assist works perfectly. The blank icon proposals disappeared when I uninstalled the Jboss plugin. So if your content assist is hindered anyhow, then do check your plugins and try uninstalling them safely. That should do the trick.
[image]

Comment: Do you know where the two proposals come from? I do not have them in the _Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers 2020-09_. Could you please show the lower part of the screenshot (maybe there is a hint).

Comment: I could not get content assist to work in either of Eclipse 2020-06 or 2020-09 (for Java Developers) versions so have kept on using 2020-03.

Comment: @howlger I have updated my answer. Does this help? If you want more information, just let me know.

Comment: @DuncG Yeah. Eclipse seems a little buggy in that. I was thinking of switching to IntelliJ lol.

Comment: @DuncG Try with a new workspace. If this does not help, then it's caused by a plug-in you have installed.

Comment: @TejasNareshSuvarna I like to know which plugin contributes this two kind of proposals since it is nothing built-in Eclipse. Maybe in the lower part (which is not shown), the plugins are shown preventing enabling non-blocking proposals. What you think is Eclipse, is not Eclipse, but a plugin you installed into Eclipse.

Comment: @howlger You were totally right. It was the Jboss hibernate plugin from the Eclipse Marketspace that was causing the problem. The two proposals were gone once I uninstalled it. Guess plugins mess up Eclipse a bit.

Comment: @howlger Thanks for the suggestion. I don't use plugins now but maybe the old workspace had something lingering there which messed up the upgrade. Now my 2020-09 works with new workspace and I imported preferences and Launch configurations from the old workspace so I won't spend the day fixing the setup.

Comment: @howlger You are welcome. And yeah sure, configurations cause a lot of mess mostly in Eclipse.

Comment: @TejasNareshSuvarna According to my experience, Eclipse is neither buggy nor do configurations cause mess. Installing plugins/extensions can cause problems in Eclipse, in other IDEs, in editors, in web browsers, etc. So, don't shoot the extensible platform!

Comment: @howlger Yup, true that.